# PrestaShop display subcategories from category ID

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I use PrestaShop 1.6 and I want to display an image when I'm on a specific category page and I want the image to be visibile on subcategories of that category.

```
{if $subcategory->id == 15}
    style="background-position: 70% 72%; background-image: url(../img.jpg);"
{/if}
```

Comment: Hello. What's your issue exactly?? Your code looks good except for a missin " at the end of `url(../img.jpg);`

Comment: not the code is the problem. I want to give that style to category id == 15 and subcategories from category with id == 15

Comment: And what is exactly the problem you have with you code??

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
{if $subcategory->id == 15 || $subcategory->id_parent == 15}
    style="background-position: 70% 72%; background-image: url(../img.jpg);"
{/if}
```

Comment: Would you mind being a little more extensive over what doesn't work so as I can improve my answer? I can't guess what you have on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to the category.tpl file of your store:

```
{if $category->id_parent == 15} //For example the category ID is 15
.your_element_selector { 
background-position: 70% 72%; background-image: url(../img.jpg);
}
{/if}
```

Note: You should create a separate element to show the image.